# Creating elements with javascript/php, need to get their unique ID and send it back to PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that sends a POST to a php file, and gets a new integer (primary key). Then the script creates 3 new divs, with that ID included in them as an attribute.

Now, I need to be able to grab the ID and give it back to PHP when the user updates it. (It's currently a div, but later it will be an editable form.)

I was going to do this by creating a button in the same script that I use to create the divs, bearing the same integer and calling a function. The problem with this concept, is that I have no idea how to create a Unique variable to pass along to the function, so it knows which number to look at. Obviously, if I have only one variable that gets overwritten with each new entry - after all of the rows load, only the last row will have a variable that matches its id.

Another option is to find the value of all attributes that bear the name `data-integer-question` and pass its number/integer to a function, when the user does something like keyup enter. However, I have no idea how to do that.

`obj.returnIntJson` holds the integer that I've been talking about, which changes for each row.

`rowNumberObj.qarowcontainer` is just a reference for the parent div, which doesn't get edited by the user - you can ignore it.

The script gives a result like this: `<div id="questioncolumn" class="questionColumnCSS" data-integer-question="701"></div>`

Suggestions on how to proceed? Here's the code for one of the divs,

Thanks.

```
    qaRowQuestion = document.createElement('div');
    qaRowQuestion.setAttribute('id', "questioncolumn");
    qaRowQuestion.setAttribute('data-integer-question', obj.returnIntJson);
    qaRowQuestion.setAttribute('class',"questionColumnCSS");

    qaRowQuestionParent = document.getElementById(rowNumberObj.qarowcontainer);
    qaRowQuestionParent.appendChild(qaRowQuestion);
```

Comment: Just worth mentioning that you shouldn't have multiple IDs on the same page, ie. you're assigning "questioncolumn" to each row as it's `id` attribute.

Comment: @benhowdle89 do you mean "multiple of the same IDs?"

Comment: Yes, sorry. As for your question, not sure I'm following what you're wanting to do. Maybe add an edit with some clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script worked:

```
$(document).on("click", ".questionColumnCSS",function() {
  var questionUpdate = ($(this).data('integer-question'));
});
```